# How to use the group_by function while keeping other columns

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by

I wanted to know how it is possible to use the `group_by()` function with being able to keep other columns in the process.

My dataset consists of a lot of different information about different birds and I need to calculate frequencies of 7 behaviors for each day for each bird.

Let's say I subset my dataset for one individual:

`alm18subset <- subset(df, df$individualID == "Almen18 (eobs 5861)")`

I then have the data for only this individual.

I then want to know the frequencies of the behavior for each day in a new dataframe using group_by:

```
alm18freq <- alm18subset %>%
  group_by(agesincetaggingdays, behaviors) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  mutate(freq = n / sum(n))
```

which gives me a output of age, behaviors, and then summarise the number of time each behavior is carried out each day and the frequency I'm looking for. My question is, in this process I lose all the other columns using the group_by(). I want to keep some information in my data, like sex or the time a behavior was carried out. This is because I need to do models.

Any idea of how to do it ?

Then I also need to filter according to the behavior:

`alm18active <- filter(alm18freq, rf8fitted == "Active")`

Thank you !

Comment: `lm18subset %>% add_count(agesincetaggingdays, behaviors)`

Comment: `group_by` doesn't change the data structure, it's `summarize`. Try `mutate(n = n(), freq = n / sum(n))`

Comment: @AndreWildberg write an answer please, this is the correct answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply merge the two dataframes that you have by their common columns, this will include the frequency column in the initial subset:

```
merge(alm18subset, alm18freq)
```

Answer (score 1):

Replacing `summarize` with `mutate` should suffice in your case. The subsequent `filter` can be done right after this operation.

```
alm18freq_active <- alm18subset %>%
  group_by(agesincetaggingdays, behaviors) %>%
  mutate(n = n(), freq = n / sum(n)) %>%
  filter(rf8fitted == "Active")
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the response. Unfortunately, when I use this code it changes the values of the frequencies inside my data (I didn't figure out why for now).

Comment: I mean the frequencies using this code are different than when I merge dataframes together...

Comment: @Skyk The only thing the `mutate` does is add *n* and *freq* in the new dataset `alm18freq_active`, (also `filter`ing the data). If you already have a variable *freq* this is overwritten. Can't really tell without knowing the data.

Comment: I see, do you want maybe a sample so you can know ?